# Rails ActionView::Template::Error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 app working in development, but when I deploy to a VPS with Capistrano, I get the following error:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/" for ***.***.***.*** at 2013-12-20 22:24:28 +0000
INFO -- : Processing by PortalsController#index as HTML
INFO -- :   Rendered portals/index.haml within layouts/application (2.9ms)
INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (key not found: :params):
    1: %h2
    2:   = link_to "New portal", new_portal_path
    3: 
    4: %h3 Current portals:
    5: = render @portals
  app/views/portals/index.haml:2:in `_app_views_portals_index_haml___3074475544725108295_70221306145460'
```

In looking at differences between production.rb and development.rb, I discovered that setting

```
config.eager_load = false
```

in production.rb, the error goes away.  However, I would like to keep the default setting of config.eager_load set to true.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this would be happening?

portals_controller.rb

```
def index 
    @portals = Portal.all 
end
```

portals/index.haml

```
%h2
  = link_to "New portal", new_portal_path

%h3 Current portals:
= render @portals
```

portals/_portal.haml

```
%p
  = link_to portal.name, portal
```

config/routes.rb

```
******::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'portals#index'

  resources :portals, shallow: true do
    resources :webpages do
      resources :documents
    end
  end

  mount Resque::Server, at: "/resque"
end
```

I'm using unicorn and nginx on the VPS.

Comment: Is there more to the error dump?

Comment: I am downvoting your question because you did not give enough context information.

Comment: @phoet.  At least have the decency to indicate what context you were looking for.

Comment: @Dhaulagiri, I've added the rest of the dump.

Comment: What about the index action in your PortalsController and your index.haml file?  What do thoes look like?

Comment: What's your routes for portal?

Comment: @phoet I've added the routes.rb

Comment: I did not.  I'll let you know if I do.